# android sqlite not update all rows one column

Tags: android, sqlite

I am  new on android development. I have a table with 9 columns who can store products , first is **_id** autoincrement, and the other two last **insertdays** and **days**. 
In insertdays i store current date as integer after convert date to int. In the days column i store the number of days to expire a product. 
I made 3 methods **getDays(), getInsertdate(), expCheck()**. 
The getDays return to expCheck the days for each row, **its working** 
The getInsertdate return to expCheck the inserted date **its working**

The problem is, when i try to update my database , expCheck() called on onCreate() and onResume() methods, the values of days column for all rows(products) does not updated. With expCheck() method i try to  reduce the number of days for each day who pass. 
[My database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Mls.png) in the photo the last column must reduce by one if pass one day, reduce by 2 each row if pass two days e.t.c ... Can anyone help me !!!

```
 public int getInsertDate(int productId){
    int output=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] projectionG = {
            ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_INSERTDATE};
    Cursor cursor1 = db.query(TABLE_NAME, projectionG, " _id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(productId) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor1 !=null) {
        if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) output = cursor1.getInt(7);
    }
    cursor1.close();
    return output;
}

public int getDays(int productId){
    int output=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] projectionD = {ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_DAYS};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, projectionD, " _id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(productId) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor !=null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
         output = cursor.getInt(8);
                                    }
                         }
    cursor.close();
    return output;
}

public void expCheck(){
    //Read current date
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SQLiteDatabase db=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    // Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
    // you will actually use after this query.
    String[] projection = {

            ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_DAYS
    };
    // Perform a query on the products table
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
            projection,            // The columns to return
            null,                  // The columns for the WHERE clause
            null,                  // The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                  // Don't group the rows
            null,                  // Don't filter by row groups
            null);                   // The sort order
    int j = toJulianDate(calendar.getTime());

    Toast.makeText(this, "date is" + j,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//Method getInsertDate return the insert date of product to database
int currentInsertdate = getInsertDate(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_INSERTDATE));
// Method getDays return the number of days to expire a product
int currentDays = getDays(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_DAYS));
currentDays = currentDays - (j - currentInsertdate);// calculate the new  amount of remaining days to expire th product
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ProductEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_DAYS, currentDays);
//update all rows
db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, null, null);
```

}

Comment: Updating all rows with the same values does not make sense. And why don't you simply store the expiration date?

Comment: This code is a part of  an app of course. I put a limit of  60 days then the app notify the user for the products who will expire. My logic based on when each day pass the days column for each row (product) reduce until the limit of 60 days .

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: just try this `db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "_id >" + 0, null);`